# php rename file and append extension

Tags: php

I'm trying to rename image files after upload, here is my code.

```
if (isset($_POST['image'])){


$file_name = $_POST['image'];

$extention = pathinfo("$file_name ",PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

rename("files/" . $file_name,"files/" . uniqid() . $extention);

echo "done";

}
```

Works but file name gets displayed as follows

```
5498e85c85b89jpeg 
5498e85c85b89jpeg
```

How can I add a dot before extension name? to make file names display as follows

```
5498e85c85b89.jpeg
5498e85c85b89.jpeg
```

should I another rename operation to fix that? or there is a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate a `.` in your `rename` call:

```
rename("files/" . $file_name,"files/" . uniqid() . "." . $extention);
```

BTW, you need to sanitize the input. If it contains any `../` components, it will be able to rename files outside the `files/` subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

please use this

```
rename("files/" . $file_name,"files/" . uniqid() .".".$extention);
```